# Prestashop payment module, process POST request from external server

Tags: module, prestashop, payment, prestashop-1.7

I just creating prestashop 1.7 payment module (mobile payments using qr code) and after payment Provider send http POST the question is how to create reciever for this request? using front controller? POST from provider looks like /?requestString=QP%3A1.0*BID%3AMYBID*AM%3A6.00*

Answer (score 1):

Here a complete guide about the creation of a front controller: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/front-controllers/

The guide also describe how to handle a POST action (which is really easy). You should handle it in the method `postProcess()`.